# Cannot Access previous Windows Shares with LTS 18.04.01

Tags: samba

This week I updated from LTS 16.04 to 18.04.01 with around a 95% success rate.  The issue I'm having is that I had a working share from my Windows 7 PC via a home LAN to Ubuntu.  When the update finished the Files icon shows "Windows Network" and "No Files Found".  I can however see my provided Ubuntu public folder from the Windows PC.

I've tried "Connect to server" and it fails (correct IP verified); I've scoured all the sources I can find and still cannot find a way to get to my Windows PC.

I did run smbtree and it shows all the shares that I expected to fine (and no extras).  Since Bionic Beaver appears to have changed how the Files icon works (no "network" anymore) can anyone point me to a way to get these shares back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to have 2 problems:

> When the update finished the Files icon shows "Windows Network" and
>   "No Files Found".

Edit /etc/samba/smb.conf and right under the "workgroup = WORKGROUP" line add this one then save the file:

```
client max protocol = NT1
```

Just remember that once that is done you will no longer be able to connect to a Win10 machine or any other system that has disabled NT1 ( aka SMB1 ) -- at least not through the file manager.

> I've tried "Connect to server" and it fails (correct IP verified);

If you are trying to connect via an ip address and it fails that is an entirely different problem and is unrelated to the first. How does it fail? What error message?

Comment: Thanks for the info, however it's still not working.   I'm trying to get back connectivity via the "Files" icon to my Windows Network shares.   Now, under Files/Networks I see the printers; a Ubuntu share (a Public folder) ; "Windows Network" folder when I click I get "No Files Found".  Today I no longer see any of those shares/folders.    I am wondering if I need to add something with my Windows username (which is NOT the same as anything on my Ubuntu box).

Comment: There is no such path as Files > Network > Windows Network in Ubuntu 18.04. It's Files > Other Locations > Windows Network. And I can't reproduce a "No Files Found" error message no matter what I do. I can get a "Folder is Empty" error fast enough though. I'm not sure what happened with your update. And I still don't know what happens when you run this in a terminal - without quotes "nautilus smb://ip-address-of-the-win7-machine" I think this question is better suited to the Ubuntu Forum where if enough questions are asked ....

Comment: You are quite correct - the path is "Other Locations" - the "network" is a heading on the files GUI page (just text heading).  Thanks for trying - I'll give a shot @ the terminal string.

Comment: To follow up - the nautilus screen for "Other Places/Windows Network" is simply "Folder is Empty".  FYI - when I ran the terminal line above it mounted some new/strange local folders (on the Ubuntu box) but gave "Location could not be displayed" error with "Operation not supported" for that IP.

Comment: That error message I can reproduce: "Location could not be displayed"..."Operation not supported" for that IP" That will happen if I am running as root or running nautilus as root. Under those conditions I will not even see "Windows Network" under "Other Locations". Stop running as root.

Comment: Bingo - Thanks very much for your help as well as your persistence!  That worked and seems to hold very nicely.