# Thunar doesn't show workgroup/windows pcs in windows-network tab

Tags: networking, samba, debian, shared-folders, thunar

Thunar is unable to display the windows devices in my network
from the "windows-network" tab (located under network). However, I am able to access windows devices with the following command in the interface:

```
thunar smb://"windows-device-ip-here"
```

This is good but I would like to see all the devices in my "windows-networks" folders. the following command works (I can see all my workgroups/devices):

```
smbtree
```

And I have installed the follwing packages: gvfs, gvfs-bin, gvfs-backends and smbclient.

When I click "browse on network", there is a folder called 'windows-network'. When I click on that one, my cursor changes to loading but after a while it just stops and the folder is empty.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you are running (X)ubuntu 18.04 this is a duplicate question and your answer is here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1062080/cannot-access-previous-windows-shares-with-lts-18-04-01/1062292#1062292

Comment: didn't work and the problem got even worse: I can't even enter the "windows-network" folder anymore. @Morbius1

Comment: Keep the "client max protocol = NT1" in smb.conf then reboot the box. If that doesn't resolve the issue post your question to the Ubuntu forum where we can ask the requisite dozen or so questions to determine how you are set up.